# Finding the node with minimum value in a Binary Search Tree using Array

Tags: c#, arrays, binary-search-tree

I have an *array of Integers* and I need to find the minimum value of this array using *Binary Search Tree Method*. I'm not so confident with BST but I know how to insert and Search in BST.

What procedures should I carry out so I get the minimum value.
This is my pseudo code I wrote out.

1. First Insert the Values of the array in the BST
2. Then Traverse the BST to find the minimum Element

I dont know if i'm in the right path or no?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace ConsoleApp2

{

    class Program
    {

        public class Node
    {
        public int Data;
        public Node Left;
        public Node Right;
        public void DisplayNode()
        {
            Console.Write(Data + " ");
        }
    }






        public Node root;
            public Program()
            {
                root = null;
            }
            public void Insert(int i)
            {
                Node newNode = new Node();
                newNode.Data = i;
                if (root == null)
                    root = newNode;
                else
                {
                    Node current = root;
                    Node parent;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        parent = current;
                        if (i < current.Data)
                        {
                            current = current.Left;
                            if (current == null)
                            {
                                parent.Left = newNode;
                                break;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                current = current.Right;
                                if (current == null)
                                {
                                    parent.Right = newNode;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            static void Main()
            {
             int minvalue(Node node)
            {
                Node current = node;

                /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */


                    while (current.Left != null)
                    {
                        current = current.Left;
                    }
                    return (current.Data);
                }

            Program nums = new Program();
                nums.Insert(50);
                nums.Insert(17);
                nums.Insert(23);
                nums.Insert(12);
                nums.Insert(19);

            Node root = null;
            int min = minvalue(root);
            Console.WriteLine(min);
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }
```

This is my Solution but I have an error
***System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
current was null.***

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: @kevinLee I need to have a clear pseudo before i start coding

Comment: The pseudo doesn't have to be correct. You can still make a start on it. It's part of the learning process. You make mistakes and learn from it and if you're truly stuck then you can come back to SO and ask for help, showing what you have already tried and what isn't working. As for your pseudo a quick Google search shows that you are pretty much correct. Just need to traverse until the left node is null.

Comment: Yes your right, but i like to have a clear view

Comment: @KevinLee Updated with code

Comment: Which line are you getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified you code so it compiles and is structured properly.  I did not fix any coding issues.  You will have to solve.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp2

{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            Node nums = new Node();
            nums.Insert(50);
            nums.Insert(17);
            nums.Insert(23);
            nums.Insert(12);
            nums.Insert(19);

            int min = nums.MinValue(nums.root);
            Console.WriteLine(min);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int Data;
        public Node Left;
        public Node Right;
        public void DisplayNode()
        {
            Console.Write(Data + " ");
        }

        public Node root = null;

        public int MinValue(Node node)
        {

            Node current = node;

            /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */


            while (current.Left != null)
            {
                current = current.Left;
            }
            return (current.Data);
        }

        public void Insert(int i)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.Data = i;
            if (root == null)
                root = newNode;
            else
            {
                Node current = root;
                Node parent;
                while (true)
                {
                    parent = current;
                    if (i < current.Data)
                    {
                        current = current.Left;
                        if (current == null)
                        {
                            parent.Left = newNode;
                            break;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            current = current.Right;
                            if (current == null)
                            {
                                parent.Right = newNode;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Anyone have an idea how to get the value which appears most in the BST ?

Comment: Getting the max number is simple.  I would create a static dictionary<int,int> with first int the number and 2nd int the number of times it occurs.  Then transverse through the tree and write number and count to dictionary.

Comment: do you have any sources i can read more about it. thanks alot

Comment: You can search wiki for binary tree algorithms.